# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

When I run my code which is downloaded from github to train a CNN model，the unexpected error is occurred.I have searched for similar questions and know the possible reason.But I still can't solve it,have you got an advice?Because the amount of code is large,I try my best to paste some relevant code below.

```
class BaseModel(object):
"""Base model implementing the training loop and general model interface."""
__metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

def __init__(self, inputs, checkpoint_dir, is_training=False,reuse=False):
    """Creates a model mapped to a directory on disk for I/O:

Args:
  inputs: input tensor(s), can be placeholders (e.g. for runtime prediction) or
          a queued data_pipeline.
  checkpoint_dir: directory where the trained parameters will be saved/loaded from.
  is_training: allows to parametrize certain layers differently when training (e.g. batchnorm).
  reuse: whether to reuse weights defined by another model.
"""

    self.inputs = inputs
    self.checkpoint_dir = checkpoint_dir
    self.is_training = is_training

    self.layers = {}
    self.summaries = []
    self.eval_summaries = []

    self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    self._setup_prediction()
    self.saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver(tf.compat.v1.global_variables(), max_to_keep=100)

def _tofetch(self):
    """Tensors to run/fetch at each training step.
Returns:
  tofetch: (dict) of Tensors/Ops.
"""
    pass

def _train_step(self, sess, start_time, run_options=None, run_metadata=None):
    """Step of the training loop.
Returns:
  data (dict): data from useful for printing in 'summary_step'.
               Should contain field "step" with the current_step.
"""
    tofetch = self._tofetch()
    tofetch['step'] = self.global_step
    tofetch['summaries'] = self.summaries
    data = sess.run(tofetch, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
    data['duration'] = time.time() - start_time
    return data

self.summary_writer = tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter(self.checkpoint_dir, sess.graph)

self.summary_writer.add_summary(step_data['summaries'], global_step=step)
```

2021-10-03 14:00:44.444692: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

2021-10-03 14:00:44.444956: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\school\地球物理\ConvNetQuake-1.0\quakenet\data_pipeline.py:77: TFRecordReader.**init** (from tensorflow.python.ops.io_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:
Queue-based input pipelines have been replaced by `tf.data`. Use `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\school\地球物理\ConvNetQuake-1.0\quakenet\data_pipeline.py:92: string_input_producer (from tensorflow.python.training.input) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:
Queue-based input pipelines have been replaced by `tf.data`. Use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(string_tensor).shuffle(tf.shape(input_tensor, out_type=tf.int64)[0]).repeat(num_epochs)`. If `shuffle=False`, omit the `.shuffle(...)`.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\python\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py:267: input_producer (from tensorflow.python.training.input) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:
Queue-based input pipelines have been replaced by `tf.data`. Use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input_tensor).shuffle(tf.shape(input_tensor, out_type=tf.int64)[0]).repeat(num_epochs)`. If `shuffle=False`, omit the `.shuffle(...)`.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\python\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py:189: limit_epochs (from tensorflow.python.training.input) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:
Queue-based input pipelines have been replaced by `tf.data`. Use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tensor).repeat(num_epochs)`.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\python\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py:197: QueueRunner.**init** (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\python\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py:196: add_queue_runner (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\school\地球物理\ConvNetQuake-1.0\quakenet\data_pipeline.py:142: shuffle_batch (from tensorflow.python.training.input) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:
Queue-based input pipelines have been replaced by `tf.data`. Use `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle(min_after_dequeue).batch(batch_size)`.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\python\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\decorator_utils.py:145: GraphKeys.VARIABLES (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES` instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\school\地球物理\ConvNetQuake-1.0\quakenet\models.py:118: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.

2021-10-03 14:00:49.467624: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

2021-10-03 14:00:49.468871: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found

2021-10-03 14:00:49.470071: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found

2021-10-03 14:00:49.471424: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found

2021-10-03 14:00:49.472768: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found

2021-10-03 14:00:49.474003: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found

2021-10-03 14:00:49.475254: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found

2021-10-03 14:00:49.476496: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found

2021-10-03 14:00:49.476730: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1835] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.

Skipping registering GPU devices...

2021-10-03 14:00:49.477635: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

Initializing all variables.
Starting data threads coordinator.
Starting optimization.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\school\地球物理\ConvNetQuake-1.0\tflib\model.py:242: start_queue_runners (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module.

Step 10 | 2s (214ms) | loss = 2.2992 | det. acc. = 50.0% | loc. acc. = 45.3%
Shutting down data threads.

2021-10-03 14:00:52.803844: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:277] _3_inputs_1/input_producer: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed

2021-10-03 14:00:52.804091: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:277] _5_inputs_1/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/school/地球物理/ConvNetQuake-1.0/bin/train", line 90, in 
main(args)

File "D:/school/地球物理/ConvNetQuake-1.0/bin/train", line 67, in main
model.train(

File "D:\school\地球物理\ConvNetQuake-1.0\tflib\model.py", line 263, in train
self.summary_writer.add_summary(step_data['summaries'],global_step=step)

File "D:\python\python\lib\sitepackages\tensorflow\python\summary\writer\writer.py", line 127, in add_summary
for value in summary.value:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace error you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that somewhere in the code other than you've provided, you are trying to this

```py
example_list=[]
example_list.value()
```

And according to my knowledge it's incorrect because *list* datatype has **no** method named as *value( )*

Therefore it's throwing this error saying *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value'.*

So check somewhere in your code, there must be a line where you're putting `.value()` after a *list* datatype

But I am not sure because you haven't provided us with neither whole code nor complete error message.

#### Edited

As now you have updated and provided the complete error message

You can see that in file *writer.py* on line 127, you have written `summary.value`

And summary is a *list*, so there's no attribute/method named as *value( )* for a *list* datatype.